# How to grant sudo access to users abc,def,ghi on user jkl

Tags: sudo, users, su

I have a user *oracle* and whenever I create a new user and if required I need to grant the newly created users the `sudo` access on *oracle*.

Like as any user I need to `sudo` to *oracle* as mentioned below

```
$ id
uid=5260958(5258) gid=20(users) groups=600(gom)
$ sudo su -oracle
```

How can I allow users to have `sudo` access to user *oracle*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [answered in server-fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access)

**1. Updating `/etc/sudoers`**

In `/etc/sudoers` the item immediately following the equals is the user that the command will be allowed to execute as.

```
tom  ALL=(oracle) ALL
```

Note: You might need to use:

```
tom ALL=(oracle)NOPASSWD:ALL
```

**2. Running the command**

The user (tom) can type:

```
sudo -u oracle bash
```

or getting a shell as user oracle:

```
sudo -u oracle -i
```